# PHP Symfony2 Semaphore

Tags: php, symfony, semaphore

I want some way to persist variable between different requests.

My situation:

I have a symfony2 service class which executes commands on remote machine.
I wan't some way to control that execution so that it would stop if previous execution has not finished yet.

I have heard of Semaphores but I'am not sure if that would do the trick, and if that would be appropriate way of doing something like this.

The principle I imagine is quite simple.

Client1 send request to server which starts executing code on remote machine. Before that it checks if execution variable is set if not it sets variable that execution is in progress.

Client2 send requests with same logic, but now the execution process variable is set so it means that remote server is busy, so request stop and and server sends response to client that service is currently busy.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Any form of persistent storage, the most common being a database or file on disk. A key/value store like reddis would also be a good option

Comment: Can the server not execute more than one thing at a time? Thats normally what servers a re for

Answer (score 0):

When the service starts, create a file on disk. After the command has been executed, delete the file. Other requests check the file's existence and only execute the command when the file is absent.